# How to list out string which contain a given pattern?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have three strings which contain what , when , why as given below

1. What is your name
2. When and why should you run for high speed
3. What is your father name

Is there a way to list out all string which contain the given pattern.

First i detected for the pattern and then counted the number of True values

```
e<-str_detect(c, "What")
   length(e[e == TRUE])
```

I expect the output in the way

```
Number of string contain What: 02 
Number of String contain when : 01
Number of String contain why : 01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create a vector to search for and use `sapply` to find if it is present in a `string`

```
vals <- colSums(sapply(tags, function(x) 
        grepl(paste0("\\b",x, "\\b"), strings, ignore.case = TRUE)))
vals

#what when  why 
#   2    1    1
```

`ignore.case` ignores the case so `"What"` and `"what"` is the same.

Word boundary (`"\\b"`) is added for each `tag` so that `"what"` does not match with `"whatever"`.

**data**

```
strings <- c("What is your name", "When and why should you run for high speed",
             "What is your father name ")
tags <- c("what", "when", "why")
```

Comment: What if we have to extract count of only those string which contain more than one questions. For Example When and why together to list out as 1

Comment: @djM One naive way would be to do `sum(grepl("\\bwhen\\b", strings, ignore.case = TRUE) & grepl("\\why\\b", strings, ignore.case = TRUE))` or it would require a complicated regex to combine two conditions.